# Can a User DSN be accessed by a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, dsn

I've build a Windows service that allows a user to choose a DSN and the service will access it and peform tasks on it.  The code works without error when running under a test command line application, and fails when running as the actual Windows Service.

My question is, are Windows Services not allowed to access User DSN?  Is there any way to still allow users the ability to create and configure DSNs for the service to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [What are the access restrictions on accessing a DSN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127608/what-are-the-access-restrictions-on-accessing-a-dsn)